# Appending input element to the DOM in safari transfers focus to the new input

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I'm having trouble with the Safari browser, in that it, unlike other browsers including Chrome and Firefox, seems to be transferring focus to a newly created input field when it's appended to the DOM.

The use case is this:

I have a single email input field, into which users type an email (for sending invites). On the keyup event, we append a new email field underneath, to allow them to fill that one out too.

The logic (not exact code) is as follows:

```
    $(document).on("keyup", ".invites input[type='email']", function(){
      if("there isn't an empty email field, we'll add one"){

        var parent = $(this).closest('wrapper');
        var cloned_parent = parent.clone(); // we also remove content and classes here
        $('.invites-container').append(cloned_parent);
        }
      })
```

It's at this point that the newly created element takes focus in Safari, but not in Chrome or Firefox. This is a problem, as the user may be typing an email address in the first input box, when the focus is snatched away, and all of a sudden they're typing in the second box, and so on. The end result is that multiple email fields are very quickly created just when typing a normal email address.

Strangley, I can't see much documentation around this difference - as appending a new element seems to be a very common function. I'm obviously missing something simple - can anyone advise what might be happening?

Things I've already tried:

- Removing all javascript on the page, then cloning just the element
  using .cloneNode() (no jquery) in the console - same issue, only in
  safari
- Removing all site css - same issue in safari
- Cloning the input element itself, instead of the parent - same issue
- Text inputs instead of email inputs - same issue

Please help!